# BIRT maintain line break in 1 cell only

Tags: birt

I am trying to keep the line break inside one cell only, however it's still not working after i do the change below and export it to excel.

The change is to replace end of a list by **"<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;/>"**

```
    var reUselessTags = /(<.{0,1}body|<.{0,1}FONT|<.{0,1}TEXTFORMAT|<img|<.{0,1}div|<.{0,1}list).{0,}?>/g;
    var reRemoveScript = /<script.{0,}?<\/script>/g;
    var reList = /<LI.{0,}?>/g;
    var reListParagraphStart = /<(LI|P).{0,}?>/g;
    var reListParagraphEnd =  /<(\/LI|\/P).{0,}?>/g;
    var reBreak = /<BR.{0,}?>/g;
    var reDoubleLineBreak = /\r+/g;
    var reOpenLineBreak = /^\r/g;
    var resStr = row["DESCRIPTION"];
    resStr = resStr.replace(reUselessTags,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reRemoveScript,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reBreak,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reDoubleLineBreak,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reOpenLineBreak,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(newLine, '');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reList, '');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reListParagraphStart,'');
    resStr = resStr.replace(reListParagraphEnd,'<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />');
    result
```